# How to fetch json result in array using Ionic 2?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am fetching data from JSON api using the below code in my 'listproduct.ts'

```
names = [];

this._listProduct.listProduct().subscribe(data => {
  this.list = data;
 console.log(data);
 });
```

In console.log, I am fetching the result as expected, attaching a picture for your reference:

[image]

I need to fetch `data.NAME` in names array, how can I do this ?

`data.NAME` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the console, `data` is an array (of 10 elements).

When we want to convert an array to another array of the same size, 1-to-1 with some kind of "mapping", we can use the `map()` function.

Replace `console.log(data);` with this line `names = data.map( e => e.NAME );`

Check if it works ;)

## Explanation

The function `map()` takes a function to be its argument, and one of the usages is to specify the element (`e` here) and how it corresponds to the result you want (we want `e.NAME` instead of the whole object `e`).

So `e => e.NAME` is a short form of `e => { return e.NAME; }` you may modify the function body as you might need in the future.

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map